# WebServices & Namespace in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service with the namespace as the following:

```
namespace MyNS
{
    class MyObject
    {
        //Implementation here
    }
}
```

And I published the webservice and try to consume that webservice from the next C# Website.

I assigned the service name to "MyWS".

When I try to write the code

I have to write,

```
MyWS.MyObject obj = new MyWS.MyObject();
```

But I want to write

```
MyWS.MyNS.MyObject obj = new MyWS.MyNS.MyObject();
```

The problem is there might by MyObject class under other Namespaces.  So, I want to identify my classes by NameSpaces.

What should I do to use Namespace in the coding?

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C#.Net".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe the original namespace is exposed as part of the WSDL, which is what the generation process uses to create the client end point.

This means there is no way to control what namespace your web service is used as.

However you can control what namespace your client end point uses. When you add the service reference, the bottom of the first page (Titled Add Service Reference, and containing Discovery controls) is a text box titled "Namespace". If you change that field to `MyWS.MyNS` when adding the service it should allow you to reference it as such.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is there might by MyObject class under other Namespaces. So, I want to identify my classes by NameSpaces.

The compiler will give you an ambiguous reference error if you try to use conflicting object names.  You will have to qualify them in that case.

So, if you want to give it a certain alias, just type the name as you want it.

```
namespace This.Is.My.Favorite.Namespace
{
    public class MyObject()
    {
      //stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace MyNS.MyWS
{
    class MyObject
    {
        //Implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the service is named MyWS and that namespace is automatically being assigned to classes imported from that service.